# SqLite - find beginning of a given string in the table

Tags: sqlite

I have a String, for example `ABC_Michael_A_V1.3_Update`

In my SQLite database, i have a table `beginnings` with 2 columns. The first one is of type String and contains multiple possible beginnings of the string, the second one is of type Integer.
for example:

```
StringBeginning   |  Score
------------------------------
ABC_Michael_C     |   2
ABC_Mich          |   5
ABC_Johannes_A    |   4
ABC_Michael_A     |   5
ABC_Michael_A_V1  |   7       <-----
ABC_Jack_A_V1.2   |   12
```

What I would need to find, is the row with the string that hast the longest matching beginning with my inputstring. (in this sample marked with a row.) Please note, that also row 2 and 4 match, but they are not the longest one.

I know how to do it the other way around, having the beginning of a string and searching all strings that start with that string, but I dont know how to do it if my input string is longer than what I am searching for.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: So you have underscore-sepatated composite strings. The question is whether "Micha" in "ABC_Micha" should match Michael? My guess is that is not what you want, but you need to state your task more precisely, as SQL has limited capacity compared to general purpose languages.

Comment: Can you have ABC_Michael_A_V2.3_Update as your input string and what should it match? Are you only looking for a row that matches in the input string prefix completely. You really need to provide a more detailed description and examples.

Comment: I need to find the row that matches it completely, and the longer the better.  so yes, ABC_Micha matches ABC_MIchael. but as posted below, I already found a query that does exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

you can sort results by number of characters found.

Try this

```
select *,
length(replace('ABC_Michael_A_V1.3_Update',StringBeginning,'')) as len
from beginnings 
where instr('ABC_Michael_A_V1.3_Update',StringBeginning) = 1 
order by len asc
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find a solution:

```
select *, length(StringBeginning) as len from beginnings where instr('ABC_Michael_A_V1.3_Update',StringBeginning) = 1 order by len desc limit 1
```